# How to decode UTF-8 string returned from shell_exec()?

Tags: python, php, apache

This works:

```
$csv = " b'\xd0\x9e\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb1\xd1\x83\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8f, \xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb1\xd1\x8b \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe.'";
$csv = mb_convert_encoding($csv,'UTF-8');
```

While this returns unconverted string:

```
$o = shell_exec('python3.6 /var/www/html/main.py'.'normal');
$contents = mb_convert_encoding($o,'UTF-8');
echo $contents
```

Python script returns same string. I tried strval() and unpack(), didn't work.
Here is the result of "locale -a":
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj8Ax.png)

Even if i put call to script in eval() it interprets string as data.

Comment: You are not correctly differentiating between _code_ and _data_ here. Your `$csv = "…";` above is _code_  - the PHP parser will transform these `\x..` things into their actual byte values. Your `$csv` _variable_ does not contain `\x..` any more afterwards. _“Python script returns same string.”_ - that is _data_ at this point already, from PHP’s perspective. The PHP parser does not go over that any more.

Comment: @CBroe but why strval() not working, if that is the case?

Comment: I don’t see why it should? The purpose of that function is to get the string representation of some other data type - so if you had `$x =  5;`, this would ensure that you had an actual _string_ value instead of a number afterwards. If you feed it what is already a string to begin with, why should it do _anything_? I think we can savely assume that it checks for that first, and directly returns the value unmodified in that case.

Comment: @CBroe then i just don't get how to convert from data to string if it is already a string

Comment: @CBroe or you mean convert to byte and then decode?

Comment: You don’t want to “convert it from string to string”, you want what _already_ is _data_, to be treated as if it was _code_. `eval` would be the evil, because dangerous, “solution”. A proper one would use `preg_replace_callback` to parse out those `\x..` combinations, convert the `..` from hex to decimal, and then use `chr()` to translate that back into the corresponding “character” resp. byte value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in php script and i don't have to encode anything between scripts,it just works:

```
putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before calling `shell_exec()`:

```php
putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8');
```

Comment: Didn't work, added result of the "locale -a" if that might help